# Fail to install redux npm package! -4048

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, package

I’m trying to install npm package (npm install redux) but its fail to install.

How can i solve this problem ?

this is the error:

npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.16.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EPERM

npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! path C:\webDevelopment\MERN-blog\client\node_modules.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-83\binding.node

npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\webDevelopment\MERN-blog\client\node_modules.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-83\binding.node'

npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\webDevelopment\MERN-blog\client\node_modules.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-83\binding.node'] {

npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\webDevelopment\MERN-blog\client\node_modules.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-83\binding.node'] {

npm ERR!     errno: -4048,

npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',

npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',

npm ERR!     path: 'C:\webDevelopment\MERN-blog\client\node_modules\.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-83\binding.node'

npm ERR!   },

npm ERR!   errno: -4048,

npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',

npm ERR!   path: 'C:\webDevelopment\MERN-blog\client\node_modules\.node-sass.DELETE\vendor\win32-x64-83\binding.node',

npm ERR!   parent: 'client'

npm ERR! }

npm ERR!

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),

npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Power\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-30T05_06_38_588Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Test this way

1- first delete `node_module` folder

2- `npm install` or `yarn`

3- `npm i redux`  or `yarn add redux`

Comment: ok...i will try this..thanks

Comment: thanks a lot ....my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete the exiting node module from the project

once done reinstall the node module package

using npm

```
npm install redux
```

using yarn

```
yarn add redux
```

for reference

https://redux.js.org/introduction/installation

Answer (score 0):

In my case, reloading of VS Code worked.